# Post Enum to MVC4 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, enums

I have a complex object that I have created a ViewModel, a View, and some custom HTML helpers for. One of the objects in my complex object is a "Sender" object. That object requires an ID and a SenderType enum to be unique. I have created a custom Html Dropdown helper that adds a data attribute to each option.

```
<select id="Sender">
     <optgroup label="Dynamic">
          <option selected="selected" value="1" data-sendertype="Dynamic">Academic Advisor</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Generic">
          <option value="1" data-sendertype="Generic">Test Account</option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```

My object that it should be deserialized to is (with only the ID and SenderType fields populated):

```
public class Sender
{
    public int SenderID { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public SenderType Type { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public enum SenderType{

    Generic = 1,
    Dynamic = 2
}
```

and the form is posted by the following jQuery:

```
$(".controlButtons button[name='Save']").click(function(event) {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
            var data = $("#editTemplateForm").serializeArray();
            data.push(
                {
                    name: "Template.Sender.SenderID",
                    value: $("#Sender").val()
                },
                {
                    name: "Template.Sender.SenderType",
                    value: $("#Sender option:selected").attr("data-senderType") == "Dynamic" ? 2 :1
                },
                {
                    name: "Template.DefaultSender.SenderID",
                    value: $("#Sender").val()
                },
                {
                    name: "Template.DefaultSender.SenderType",
                    value: $("#DefaultSender option:selected").attr("data-senderType") == "Dynamic" ? 2 :1
                }
            );
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("EditTemplateTab", new {id = Model.Template.TemplateID})",
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#ui-tabs-1").html(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

The problem I am having is that it is not deserializing the SenderType that I am adding into the serializedArray properly and says that SenderType 0 is invalid (which is true).

**screenshot of error**
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Is there any way you could post a capture of the ajax request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON serializer does not convert well with .NET enums. See this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx

Try this work-around:

```
public class Sender
{
    public int SenderID { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public SenderType Type { get; set; }

    public int SenderTypeValue
    {
        get { return (int) this.Type; }
        set { this.Type = (SenderType) value; }
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public enum SenderType
{

    Generic = 1,
    Dynamic = 2
}
```

Comment: That worked after I removed the @Html.LabelFor() and put in a static label field also. Thanks for the help.